# How can I update jmeter in ubuntu

Tags: apt, updates

Currently I've installed jmeter using

`sudo apt-get install jmeter`

I got jmeter version 2.3.4 which does not have capability to send json request.
But the latest jmeter has the capability. How can I update jmeter to latest version using apt-get

I am using ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Which Ubuntu version do you run?

Comment: I am using ubuntu 12.04

Comment: You could upgrade to 14.04 LTS. It comes with jmeter 2.8-1 (see [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/i386/jmeter/2.8-1)). Or you could try downloading the .deb file from [here](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/j/jakarta-jmeter/) and see if it gets installed using `sudo dpkg -i [deb file]`.

Comment: @Jos - I think its the only way. Please add it as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu 12.04 does not officially support a newer version, so you have two options:

- You could upgrade to 14.04 LTS. It comes with jmeter 2.8-1 (see [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/i386/jmeter/2.8-1)).
- Or you could try downloading the .deb file from [here](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/j/jakarta-jmeter/) (choose the proper architecture) and see if it gets installed using `sudo dpkg -i [deb file]`. As it is fully written in Java, chances are that it doesn't need any newer dependencies than you already have installed.

Answer (score 3):

There's no repository with current version of jmeter, so you could not update to it using `apt-get`.

1. I've installed jmeter as you did.
2. Downloaded current version from [here](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi):

   `wget http://apache.ip-connect.vn.ua//jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-5.2.1.tgz`
3. Extracted it:

   `tar xf apache-jmeter-5.2.1.tgz`
4. Renamed existing jmeter installation folder:

   `sudo mv /usr/share/jmeter /usr/share/jmeter-old`
5. Moved newly extracted current jmeter's folder into /usr/share/:

   `sudo mv apache-jmeter-5.2.1 /usr/share/jmeter`

`/usr/bin/` contains `jmeter` simlink to `/usr/share/jmeter/bin/jmeter` binary file and newly extracted and moved `jmeter` being installed earlier with `apt-get install` command could be executed like its previous version from main menu.